# Adding URL Variable on CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, variables

I want to add a new URL variable on CI 3.0 like `site_url` or `base_url`.

For example; I want to add an `admin_url` variable for administration area and `assets_url` variable for assets.

I checked CI 3.0 guide but couldn't find a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer now,

add these lines on `system/helpers/url_helper.php` file:

```
if ( ! function_exists('admin_css'))
{
    /**
     * Base URL
     *
     * Create a local URL based on your basepath.
     * Segments can be passed in as a string or an array, same as site_url
     * or a URL to a file can be passed in, e.g. to an image file.
     *
     * @param   string  $uri
     * @param   string  $protocol
     * @return  string
     */
    function admin_css($uri = '', $protocol = NULL)
    {
        return get_instance()->config->admin_css($uri, $protocol);
    }
}
```

and add these lines on `system/core/Config.php`

```
public function admin_css($uri = '', $protocol = NULL)
    {
        $base_url = base_url('assets/staff/css').'/';

        if (isset($protocol))
        {
            $base_url = $protocol.substr($base_url, strpos($base_url, '://'));
        }

        if (empty($uri))
        {
            return $base_url.$this->item('index_page');
        }

        $uri = $this->_uri_string($uri);

        if ($this->item('enable_query_strings') === FALSE)
        {
            $suffix = isset($this->config['url_suffix']) ? $this->config['url_suffix'] : '';

            if ($suffix !== '')
            {
                if (($offset = strpos($uri, '?')) !== FALSE)
                {
                    $uri = substr($uri, 0, $offset).$suffix.substr($uri, $offset);
                }
                else
                {
                    $uri .= $suffix;
                }
            }

            return $base_url.$this->slash_item('index_page').$uri;
        }
        elseif (strpos($uri, '?') === FALSE)
        {
            $uri = '?'.$uri;
        }

        return $base_url.$this->item('index_page').$uri;
    }
```

don't forget to autoload `url_helper`. With this way, you can use `admin_css` variable like this: `<?php echo admin_css('foo.css'); ?>`

If you use the other answers on this post, you can not use like `<?php echo admin_css('foo.css'); ?>`

Thank you all.

Comment: glad it worked out for you, but it's not a good idea to modify the core files, try always to extend them

Answer (score 4):

It's pretty straight forward.

Just go to your config.php which is located at /your_root/application/config directory

add at this line at the bottom of that file

```
$config["admin_url"] = "http://www.your_url.com/admin";
$config["assets_url"] = "http://www.your_url.com/assets";
```

To retrieve it anywhere in application use this

```
$your_admin_variable =$this->config->item("admin_url");
$your_assets_variable =$this->config->item("assets_url");
```

Your're in business :)

Comment: first, welcome to stack overflow, second this is the best answer

Answer (score 0):

My solution.

Create new helper file and add this file to autoload.

So..

Create file `application/helpers/global_helper.php`

Inside your helper create functions  for example:

```
<?php
    function admin_url(){
        return base_url() . "/admin/";
    }
```

Now edit `config/autoload.php`

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url','global');
```

Add to exists array your new helper.

And now anywhere you can use your function `admin_url`

Comment: Yeah, actually I thought that but it doesn't look like the perfect solution but thanks for your help :)

Comment: what kind of perfect solution, do you need , can you explain Deniz B. ?

Comment: Actually I found some information on web, they're looking more complicated and I'm confused; if it is easily as this, why they choose complicated way? I was using this way but now I'm in doubt that what if this is not the best way for it?

Comment: @pr0metheus you missed ; after return base_url() . "/admin/", I can not edit because edits should be more than 6 characters. Can you fix it?

Comment: Fixed. This is very good solution. You should use it without any problems.

Comment: But when I use it, I can not use like this; admin_url('foo'). I have to use this admin_url()foo but my website is multilangual and this URL thing can be a mess for me.

Comment: Hmm you can pass parametr to function and base on that show that what you want.

Answer (score 0):

in system/helpers/url_helper.php you will find

```
if ( ! function_exists('base_url'))
{
    function base_url($uri = '')
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        return $CI->config->base_url($uri);
    }
}
```

so i guess if you create your own code  like this

```
if ( ! function_exists('your_variable_name'))
{
    function your_variable_name($uri = '')
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        return $CI->config->your_variable_name($uri);
    }
}
```

but it is better to extend the helper rather modifying it , so you can use the code above in `application/helpers/MY_url_helper.php`
and then you can call your custom variable as you normally do it with base_url
hope that helps